# Moment js: get string with hours

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get a string from a moment with hours

```js
let hours = 5;

console.log(moment().from(moment().subtract(hours, 'hours'), true)); // "5 hours" ОК

hours = 24;

console.log(moment().from(moment().subtract(hours, 'hours'), true)); // "day"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

but i want get hours (24, 48 hours and so on).

Tell me please how to do it

Comment: "*how to do it*" - by not using [tag:momentjs] - that's not what it's designed for.

Comment: Can't you just concatenate `" hours"` to the `hours` variable? Or use a conditional if you care about plural (`hours + (hours === 1 ? ' hour' : ' hours')`)?

Comment: Can you be clearer on expected input to expected output?  If you extract 24 hours from "now", a date/time will be the same time yesterday.  How can you possibly get "48" from a time on a 24 hour clock?  Are you looking for the difference in hours (as in "48 hours ago")?     Which *looks like* you just want let `hours = 24;  console.log(hours)`  (as noted in comment above)

Comment: Just making sure you're aware of the [Project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) of momentJs if this is a new/learning project.

Comment: i'm trying pass number and get string. 
There is localization of hours for all languages. I need to save this

Comment: Ok, so this is the pure definition of an XY Problem. Your question is about localization, not about momentJs

Comment: localization is in this library. My question is can I get the result in hours not days using moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default moment will shorten and round up to "day" at the 22 hour mark. This is defined by the [relative time thresholds](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) among breakpoints for other time units.

To change it *globally* the setter is `moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h', thresholdNumber);` and if set to something sufficiently high, it will not report days:

```js
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h', 10000);//some arbitrarily high number

function hoursAgo(hours) {
  const duration = moment.duration(hours, 'hours');
  return duration.humanize(true);
}

console.log(hoursAgo(5));
console.log(hoursAgo(24));
console.log(hoursAgo(30));
console.log(hoursAgo(48));
console.log(hoursAgo(168));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, the thresholds can be overridden in the [`.humanize()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) by passing a threshold object as the last parameter (if the boolean is omitted, then it is also the first and only parameter):

```js
function hoursAgo(hours) {
  const duration = moment.duration(hours, 'hours');
  return duration.humanize(true, {h: 10000}); //some arbitrarily high number
}

console.log(hoursAgo(5));
console.log(hoursAgo(24));
console.log(hoursAgo(30));
console.log(hoursAgo(48));
console.log(hoursAgo(168));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The threshold can also be set such that it starts rounding to, for example, "two days" but everything before is still in hours

```js
function hoursAgo(hours) {
  const duration = moment.duration(hours, 'hours');
  return duration.humanize(true, {h: 48}); //some arbitrarily high number
}

console.log(hoursAgo(5));
console.log(hoursAgo(24));
console.log(hoursAgo(30));
console.log(hoursAgo(48));
console.log(hoursAgo(168));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```